# Is there a way to handle Firebase projet and android application creation automation?

Tags: android, firebase, jenkins, automation

I'm working on a continuous project creation from an administrator tool. This tool is able to create a create a gitlab and jenkins project from template.
The android template use Firebase crashlytics and we all know that google-services.json file will be mandatory to use Firebase service.
After creating the project from our template using our administrator tool, jenkins build failed because of lack of google-services.json file.

So to retrieve google-services.json file, we need to create project firebase and android application. All of these actions are manual. My question is there a way to get this file using kind of Firebase APIs to create project and android application ?

Thanks

Comment: Actually, google-sevices.json is not mandatory.  You can instead insert the values from it into your build directly without the google-services plugin, and manually initialize Firebase.  https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. But even if I initialize Firebase manually, I always need to create project and android application from firebase dashboard to get data like applicationId etc.
I'm just trying to avoid these user actions.

Comment: There is currently no way to automatically create a firebase project.  It must be done manually.  Please feel free to file a feature request with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 0):

In android studio you get the option to link your Firebase Account. Double tap `Shift` and type `Firebase` You should get the assistant and then follow the instructions.